# Entity Framework 4.2 Model Generation Exception

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

I'm trying to preserve two classes: ForumPost, and ForumReply. All of their properties either have corresponding table columns, or are marked with [NotMapped]. Both tables have primary key columns marked. In fact, I have done exactly as indicated in the book Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework (http://www.amazon.com/Pro-ASP-NET-MVC-3-Framework/dp/1430234040) which worked when doing their Ch7 tutorial, but breaks when attempting to translate the concept to my own project. The error is as follows:

One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

```
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'ForumPost' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'ForumReply' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet �ForumPosts� is based on type �ForumPost� that has no keys defined.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet �ForumReplies� is based on type �ForumReply� that has no keys defined.
```

Comment: Did you add the primary keys after creating the EF mappings?

Comment: I think this is a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011145/entity-framework-code-first-entitytype-has-no-key-define

Answer (score 0):

Are the Keys int or string?
Remember that strings more than 255 in length can't be used as a Key.

Use [Key, Required, MaxLength(255)]  (or less) if your key is actually a string.